# What's the meaning of "Moe"

Tags: slang, internet-slang

I've seen people trying to define it in many places, but all of them end up giving different versions or saying it can't be defined.

Comment: Welcome to JLU! Would you mind quoting where you saw the word or giving some reference? To make this a better question, you might want to consider asking about the correct usage or context of the word and give as much detail as you can.

Comment: @Chris: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8vSXpz3zjCM

Comment: Is it 「萌え~」or something like that?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: Yeah, I should have expected that. Anyways, I just wanted to make a point to the OP.

Comment: I don't disagree with the point per se; I just couldn't help posting that.

Comment: If it's the slang word `萌{も}え` the [English Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moe_%28slang%29) has a pretty good rundown on it, but it's got a lot of usages which may not be explained there.

Comment: The [same question was asked on anime.se](http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/894/what-does-moe-mean), and it has answers with some more information.

Answer (score 4):

There are multiple ways "Moe" or 「萌え」can be used.

- 「萌え萌え」as a mimetic word (擬態語) like Ignacio's link in the comment.
- 「萌え！」as an interjection (感嘆詞)
- 「妹萌え」as a prefix (接尾辞) In this example someone has a fetish/attraction/affection/情熱/欲望 towards little sisters.
- 「萌える」as a verb as well. For example, 「あなたは（私から見て）萌える」

Either way you can attach 萌え to almost anything that you might be attracted to in regard to females (I've yet to see it directed towards males, but if it exists please correct me). However, 萌え is generally used in the context of anime, manga, video games, etc, to denote someone's charm (which may or may not be recognized by a specific group of people).

What your asking about is the slang version, but originally 萌え comes from 芽生え which means to bud or sprout in terms of plants.

Answer (score 1):

"Moe", from 「[萌]{も}える」, refers to the feelings of the subject towards the object, especially with regards to affection or care.